# How to distiguish multiple similar forms and divs in jQuery Form script

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I have multiple similar forms at the page and I am using  the jQuery form plugin. After submitting any of the forms I want to update a div above the particular form from which the data was submitted by the response from the php / asp page.
But I do not know how to distinguish forms in jQuery script to receive response to particular div.

Here is an original script without availability to distinguish forms and divs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#htmlForm').ajaxForm({ 
        target: '#htmlExampleTarget', 
        success: function() { 
            $('#htmlExampleTarget').fadeIn('slow'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Here are forms and divs:

```
<form id='htmlForm' action='process.asp' method='post'>
<input TYPE='hidden' NAME='ID' VALUE='1'>
<input type='submit' value='Go'></form>

<div id='htmlExampleTarget'></div>


<form id='htmlForm' action='process.asp' method='post'>
<input TYPE='hidden' NAME='ID' VALUE='2'>
<input type='submit' value='Go'></form>

<div id='htmlExampleTarget'></div>
```

etc.

The forms and divs are created with a loop, there si no problem to change their id's numerically... I just need the script to distinguish them. Now I can update only the first div by response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

you know every object should have a unique ID, that is not w3 compliant valid html code, anyways how about

```
...
success: function() { 
            $(this).prev('div').html('banana dance');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the same ID for more than one elements. 
If the elements are of the same type, use classes and use the id to get the specific element you want.

ie.

```
<form id='htmlForm_1' class='htmlForm' action='process.asp' method='post'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following,

```
<div class="wrap_form">
   <div class="above"></div>
   <form>
   </form>
</div>

<div class="wrap_form">
   <div class="above"></div>
   <form>
   </form>
</div>

$('form').submit(function (){  
    var form $(this);
    $.ajax({
     ... options go here ...,
     success:function (r) {
           $(form).parents('.wrap_form').find('.above').html('blablabla');
      }
    })
});
```

///but looking at your approach

use `$('form').prev('div');`

Comment: Hello, thanks for advice. I put distinct ids (htmlForm_1, htmlForm_2, etc. and htmlExampleTarget_1, htmlExampleTarget_2, etc.) for all forms and divs. What do you mean, how the javascript code should looks now? Thanks.

Comment: well, its difficult to explain but use @max4ever answer should help you with your current situation

Answer (score 0):

It's totally wrong to have the same id for the forms. Use a different id for each form if you want to do this right and your code should then be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#htmlForm_1').ajaxForm({
        target: '#htmlExampleTarget_1',
        success: function() {
            $('#htmlExampleTarget_1').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

etc.

For what you asked in the comments:

You could use the input field name="id" on submit to get the target in this way

```
    var targetNum = 0; //outside the functions


            targetNum = jQuery(this).children('input[name="ID"]').val();
 $('#htmlExampleTarget'+targetNum).fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: O.K., but it looks I have to put there some kind of variable, instead of numbers, because I have htmlForm_1, htmlForm_2 etc... Any idea?

Comment: This has to be done on submit. Get the value of the input[name="ID"] and use it. I'm editing the answer to see what i mean

Comment: I put the code together, but it does not work. Any idea?
var targetNum = 0;

$(document).ready(function() { 
   targetNum = jQuery(this).children('input[name="MapaID"]').val();

    $('#htmlForm'+targetNum).ajaxForm({ 
        target: '#htmlExampleTarget'+targetNum, 
        success: function() { 
     $('#htmlExampleTarget'+targetNum).fadeIn('slow');
        } 
    }); 
});

Comment: This is a new code I am trying: 
`var targetNum = 0;`
`$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#htmlForm1').ajaxForm({ 
    targetNum = jQuery(this).children('input[name="MapaID"]').val();
        target: '#htmlExampleTarget', 
    success: function() { 
           $('#htmlExampleTarget'+targetNum).fadeIn('slow'); 
        } 
    }); 
});`